# как скачивать файлы с яндекс диска

Tags: python, python-3.x, yandex-disk

есть файл: https://yadi.sk/d/xsjJ3dEqb4pvlQ (он открыт)
как мне его скачать? не нужна авторизация и т.п.

Comment: https://yandex.ru/dev/disk/api/reference/content-docpage/ читай

Comment: Я посмотрел документации. Мало того,что не указанно, какую библиотеку устанавливать и использовать. Там даже нет конкретных примеров.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Вот код для скачивания опубликованного файла.
(Ваша ссылка почему-то нерабочая, я для примера вставил свою ссылку. Замените её на свою рабочую, когда она у вас будет)

```
import requests
from urllib.parse import urlencode

base_url = 'https://cloud-api.yandex.net/v1/disk/public/resources/download?'
public_key = 'https://yadi.sk/d/UJ8VMK2Y6bJH7A'  # Сюда вписываете вашу ссылку

# Получаем загрузочную ссылку
final_url = base_url + urlencode(dict(public_key=public_key))
response = requests.get(final_url)
download_url = response.json()['href']

# Загружаем файл и сохраняем его
download_response = requests.get(download_url)
with open('downloaded_file.txt', 'wb') as f:   # Здесь укажите нужный путь к файлу
    f.write(download_response.content)
```

Answer (score 2):

Загрузка .csv в DataFrame Pandas с Яндекс диска без авторизации, при наличии публичных ссылок на папку и файл

Библиотеки:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import urllib
import json
```

Публичные ссылки(на файл и папку можно скопировать при публикации):

```
folder_url = 'https://yadi.sk/d/my_folder_hash'
file_url = 'file.csv'
url = 'https://cloud-api.yandex.net/v1/disk/public/resources/download' + '?public_key=' + urllib.parse.quote(folder_url) + '&path=/' + urllib.parse.quote(file_url)
```

Подготовка ссылки на скачивание:

```
r = requests.get(url) # запрос ссылки на скачивание
h = json.loads(r.text)['href'] # 'парсинг' ссылки на скачивание
```

Загрузка данных в DataFrame:

```
df = pd.read_csv(h, sep=';', error_bad_lines=False, comment='#' , encoding='cp1251')
```

Нужно понимать корректный разделитель и кодировку, у меня это sep=';' и encoding='cp1251'.