# Автоскачивание файла по ссылке

Tags: java, android

Мне нужно создать ссылку на файл, при переходе по которой файл автоматически сохраняется на устройство пользователя (android) могу использовать любые бесплатные сервисы.
Или что-то подобное: [как скачивать файлы с яндекс диска](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1088300/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D1%8B-%D1%81-%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0), написанное на java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь этим сервисом чтобы сделать прямую ссылку на скачивание файла:
https://www.magentawave.com/2013/09/get-direct-link-on-file.html?m=1

А если надо сгенерировать такую ссылку то для каждого облачного сервиса она будет отличаться.
Для примера как сгенерировать прямую ссылку на Google drive
[image]

Comment: Большое спасибо!