# Как скачать через python файл Excel?

Tags: python-3.x, excel, download

Мне необходимо скачать эксель таблицу, но какие бы я не делал попытки - программа лишь копирует саму страницу.

```
import requests
url = 'https://cloud.mail.ru/public/da5H/rprNXbu7K'
r = requests.get(url)
with open('smth.xlsx', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(r.content)
```

Буду рад любой помощи: будь то явный пример или объяснение.

Comment: Напрямую скачать, судя по всему нельзя, посмотрите https://www.cyberforum.ru/python/thread1594876.html

Comment: Правильно, если скачивать содержимое по адресу самой страницы, то вы саму стриницу и получите. А чтобы скачивать файл с таблицей, нужно узнать адрес файла с таблицей. В вашем случае он такой: `https://cloclo56.cldmail.ru/public/get/7YBLpnWHLtuxqF9zxPoLZ2SuJ1McPbsoJXCEV1x3R5qRxnKJHzHH4ssx1QSuUDmo3kWSfK/no/01.4.%2017.01.2022-23.01.2022_%D0%A1%20%D0%94%D0%9E%D0%A2.xlsx`

Comment: @Xander ну а как узнавать этот адрес файла? Мне нужно же автоматизировать всё, а не делать вручную

Comment: у меня была подобная задача, мои файл лежал на яндекс диске и я нашел решение тут:
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1088300/как-скачивать-файлы-с-яндекс-диска?rq=1

Comment: @JésusChristophe, парсить страницу, что приходит к вам, ищя ту ссылку на файл :)

Comment: воспользуйся `api`