# Как скачать xlsx файл целиком с яндекс диска в Jupiter?

Tags: python, excel

Всем привет!
Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что не могу найти рабочий подход к скачиванию xlsx файла целиком !!(не страницы) в директорию Jupiter.
Все что получаю это HTML файл страницы, но мне нужно, чтобы весь файл был в директории.
Важно, что файл должен быть в облаке, т.к. это часть автоматизации и файл должен скачиваться целиком, т.к. у него есть доп.листы для обработки информации.
Основной метод у меня был такой:

```
url = 'https://disk.yandex.ru/d/avZZLJymHo0dLg'
r = requests.get(url)
with open('temp.xlsx', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(r.content)
```

Поделитесь решением, если у кого есть.
Спасибо!

Comment: а вы пробовали искать похожие вопросы на сайте? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1088300/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D1%8B-%D1%81-%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0

Answer (score 0):

Нашел ответ в треде:
[https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1088300/как-скачивать-файлы-с-яндекс-диска?rq=1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1088300/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D1%8B-%D1%81-%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0?rq=1)

Решение:

```
import requests
from urllib.parse import urlencode

base_url = 'https://cloud-api.yandex.net/v1/disk/public/resources/download?'
public_key = 'https://disk.yandex.ru/d/avZZLJymHo0dLg'  # Сюда вписываете вашу ссылку

# Получаем загрузочную ссылку
final_url = base_url + urlencode(dict(public_key=public_key))
response = requests.get(final_url)
download_url = response.json()['href']

# Загружаем файл и сохраняем его
download_response = requests.get(download_url)
with open('azz.xlsx', 'wb') as f:   # Здесь укажите нужный путь к файлу
    f.write(download_response.content)
```

Это решение подходит для яндекс.диска.

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! если у вас появился новый вопрос, задайте его, пожалуйста, с помощью кнопки «[задать вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)» в правом верхнем углу страницы; если нужно указать контекст, дайте ссылку на этот вопрос.